# Sounds playing over each other using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

Right, sorry if i seem like a noob, but i'm new to xcode. I'm currently making a soundboard, and i've got all the buttons to work and play sounds from them.

However, if one sound is playing, when i press another button, rather than stopping the original sound, it just plays over it, so i was wandering if anyone knew how to fix this?

Here's the code i'm using for the buttons:

```
- (IBAction)playsound {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Gold" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* myAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    myAudio.delegate = self;
    myAudio.volume = 2.0;
    myAudio.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [myAudio play];
}
```

I'd be really grateful if someone could help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the other sound is still playing, you need to tell it to stop. You probably want to look into using the calling the `stop` method on the other AVAudioPlayer. So, something like where you have:

```
[myAudio play];
```

...insert a method call just before that to tell the other sound to stop.

```
[myOtherAudioThatsPlaying stop];
[myAudio play];
```

It might make sense to also browse the [AVAudioPlayer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

While bobtiki's answer is formally correct, it only makes sense to call the `stop` method if you want to do something useful with the sound after it has stopped, for example start playing it again. Since you just want to get rid of it, I recommend have the player just get deallocated, which automatically makes the sound stop playing.
So, instead of

> ```
> AVAudioPlayer* myAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
> ```

add an instance variable to your class:

```
AVAudioPlayer* myAudio;
```

then just use

> ```
>   myAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
> ```

Everytime a new sound is played, `myAudio` gets assigned a new pointer and the old `AVAudioPlayer` just gets deallocated.